# Malgrange Preparation Theorem with less regularity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am studying the proof of the Malgrange Preparation Theorem given in the book "Stable mappings and their singularities" written by Golubitsky and Guillemin (see Chapter IV). The statement is the following.

> Let $F\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$ be defined on a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and such that
> $F(t, 0) = g(t)t^k $ where $g(0)\neq0$ and $g$ is $C^\infty$ and defined on a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}$.
> Then there exist $C^\infty$ functions $q$, $\lambda_0$, ..., $\lambda_{k-1}$ such that
> $(qF)(t, x) = t^k + \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\lambda_i(x)t^i$ on a neighborhood of $0\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $q(0)\neq0$.

After a careful reading of the proof, it seemed to me that the result is preserved even if the assumption "$F\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n; \mathbb{R})$" is replaced by "$F(t, \cdot)$ is $C^1$ for all $t$ and $F(\cdot, x)$ is $C^\infty$ for all $x$". (Obviously, the regularity of $q$, $\lambda_0$, ..., $\lambda_{k-1}$ must also be weakened in the same manner.)
Indeed, all complex analysis arguments (inspired by Weierstrass preparation theorem) are used on functions depending on $t$, while only the implicit function theorem is used on a function depending on $x$.

My question is: Does anyone know a reference where this less regular version of the Malgrange preparation theorem is stated/proved/discussed?

Thank you.

Edit: asked and answered at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390070/malgrange-preparation-theorem-with-less-regularity)